# Which Future Release of Azure AD Connect will cater for connection to on-premises SAP?

Tags: azure

I have found the following tools comparison table, which mentions ‘Connect to on-premises HR (SAP)’ as a Future Release for AD Connect. I have a large client who needs this functionality so they can move away from MIM. Is this feature going to be available in a near future release of AD Connect?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/plan-hybrid-identity-design-considerations-tools-comparison#on-premises-to-cloud-synchronization

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no exact time for the AD Connect release of this feature.

If you want to know that as soon as possible after its release, you could trace the Azure AD Connect release history.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/reference-connect-version-history

Comment: OK, will do. Thanks very much Joy.